# How to color row if two cells on a row both equal complete

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, range

trying to, if Range("G2").value & Range("H2").value = "Complete" Then do this.

```
   If (Range("G2").Value & Range("h2").Value) = "Complete" Then
    Range("a2:j2").Interior.ColorIndex = 6
else
    End If
```

Comment: Does conditional formatting not work for this? Use `And`, not `&`. `If Range("G2").Value = "Complete" And Range("H2").Value = "Complete"`....

Comment: thanks big ben that works

Comment: If the answer given worked for you, please consider to mark it as answered by clicking the tick to the topleft of the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`&`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ampersand-operator) is used for String concatenation; you are looking for the logical operator [`And`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/and-operator).

```
If Range("G2").Value = "Complete" And Range("H2").Value = "Complete" Then
```